# How can I detect postback event in web browser control in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, browser, postback, detect

Actually I found some examples in Java or C#, I need simple way of detecting postback event.

I want to send many request to web site sequentally and write all responses to listbox or something else.

[Web site:](http://itsportal.saglik.gov.tr/its_os/index.php)

**Username: 86800010865280016**

**Password: malkabul**

**sample request strings (KAREKOD: 3th text box on form!!!)**

```
0108697930090038212747294171305311002531

0108697930090038212747286171305311002531

0108697930090038212792028171305311002532

0108697930090038212883023171305311002533

0108697930090038212883047171305311002533
```

After logging on web site, I set request string by;

```
DirectCast(GetWebBroForm1.item("f_karekod"), mshtml.HTMLTextAreaElement).value = CurrentQR
```

and click submit button;

```
DirectCast(GetWebBroForm1.item("Getir", 0), mshtml.HTMLButtonElement).click()
```

everything is ok.

**the problem now is that I have to detect postback event, parse postback information,  and then need to send another request sequentally.**

thanks a lot.

```
Private Function GetWebBroDoc1() As mshtml.HTMLDocument
    Return DirectCast(WebBro1.Document.DomDocument, mshtml.HTMLDocument)
End Function

Private Function GetWebBroForm1() As mshtml.HTMLFormElement
    If GetWebBroDoc1.forms.length > 0 Then
        Return DirectCast(GetWebBroDoc1.forms.item(0), mshtml.HTMLFormElement)
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function       

Private Sub SendQR(ByVal CurrentQR)
    CurrentQR="0108697930090038212747294171305311002531" 'request string
    DirectCast(GetWebBroForm1.item("f_karekod"), mshtml.HTMLTextAreaElement).value = CurrentQR
    Return
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help you:

```
If IsPostBack Then
'Do something
Else
'Do something else
End If
```